# Realloc 2D and functions

Tags: c, function, realloc

I want to realloc a 2D matrix in a different function from main but unfortunately, I get an invalid pointer error. I have read other answers but I can't see where is my error. My code is:

```
void example(double* w, size_t s){
    w=realloc(w,(s+1)*sizeof(double));
    w[s]=3;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    double w[100][1];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        example(w[i],sizeof(w[i])/sizeof(w[i][0])
    }

    free(w);
    return 1;
}
```

so the first level of the array is always fixed but the second can change. What is wrong with this?

**CORRECTION:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    double **w;
    int i;

    w=malloc(100*sizeof(double *));

    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        w[i]=malloc(1*sizeof(double));
        example(w[i],sizeof(w[i])/sizeof(w[i][0])
    }

    free(w);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `w` is a local variable inside `example`. All changes to it are local to the function.

Comment: the sizeof(w[i][0] will not be known at run time  better to use example(&w[i], 'desired number of doubles to alloc' );

Comment: each malloc() or realloc() needs to have the return code checked to assure that the operation was successful.

Comment: the w array, once allocated, needs to have all entries set to NULL.  so (at the end of main()) all the memory allocations can be passed to free(), first the secondary pointers, (w[x]) then the pointer to w

Comment: this line: free(w); must be use AFTER all the sub memory allocations are free'd via for( i=0;i<100;i++ ) { free( w[i] ); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The w pointer is not dynamically allocated (it didn't come from realloc or malloc) so it is invalid to pass it as the argument to realloc.  Also, you will need to pass the new pointer back to main if you want to free it in main.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory before you can realloc or free memory. Also for every iteration you allocate memory you need to free it, you may free(w) but all it is doing is removing the memory reference to to w not actually freeing all the memory. For everything you malloc or realloc you need to go back through and free it so you don't have any memory leaks. You need would need a function like your example but to free all the memory instead of allocating it.

Just my thoughts